# how to retrieve all the in app purchase items from the Google Play store

Tags: android, billing

I am implementing in app purchase for an Android app. I would like to send a request to retrieve all the items available for the app in the market, with product id, descriptions and price for each item. The reason is I do not want to hard code the items, so when the items change, the app can directly get it from the server instead of needing to make a new build. 
However I can not find a request that does this. Please let me know if I missed something or this is not yet supported.

Thanks
Ray

Comment: no answers so far, from what I can see it is not currently supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Version 3 in app billing api has better support to get product info from server. It is also much simpler than the older version.